# Java pow implementation with Integer.MIN_VALUE as exponent

Tags: java, pow

I am implementing a pow function in Java, and I am wondering how do we deal with Integer.MIN_VALUE as a exponent ? Do we just treat it as a special case ?

Because I tried to compare the result with the standard Java.lang.Math API and I get a couple different result. The following is the list of comparison

```
//this will print "1.0 vs 0.0"
System.out.println(pow(2,Integer.MIN_VALUE) + " vs " + Math.pow(2,Integer.MIN_VALUE));

//this will print "1.0 vs 1.0"
System.out.println(pow(1,Integer.MIN_VALUE) + " vs " + Math.pow(1,Integer.MIN_VALUE));

public double pow(double base, int exp){
     double result = 1.0;
     boolean pos = false;

     if(exp == 0) return result;
     if(exp > 0){
         pos = true;
         exp *= -1;
     }

     while(exp > 0){
        if((exp & 1) == 1){
           result *= base;
        }
        base *= base;
        exp /= 2;
     }
     if(!pos){
        result = 1/result;
     }
     return result;
}
```

So I am wondering if Integer.MIN_VALUE is a special case where I have to have a if statement for checking it.

```
  if(exp == Integer.MIN_VALUE && base > 1) return 0.0;
```

Comment: It really depends on the implementation that you've commented out...

Comment: `(-1)*Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. So in that case, your `while` loop doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this line:

```
exp *= -1;
```

it seems that it might have to be a special case. There are certainly ways to implement this without that special case, but because `-1 * Integer.MIN_VALUE` cannot be stored in an int, you will get a bug if you do not handle it separately.

Comment: So will it help if I assign and cast it to a long in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you've got the problem that `Integer.MIN_VALUE * -1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  You could either special-case it, or you could deal with it another way.  Indeed, one possible solution would be to make `exp` negative when it's positive, instead of the other way around; you'd just use `-exp` instead of `exp`.

Comment: If making -exp then we can't use bit shifting correct ? since ext >>= 1 will eventually end up with -1 not 0, so we have to use exp /= 2.

Comment: I thought with the Unsigned right shift that the negative exp will become positive, and it didn't work as I tried it out

Comment: You can make it work, it just takes some thinking.  I don't think I should just give you the answer, though.

Comment: Is it that you do a flip exp = ~exp+1 and then do a unsigned right shift and then do a flip again exp = ~exp+1 ?

Comment: Eh.  That's one possibility, sure.

Comment: I figure there's something rounding issue with floating point for example pow(0.0000000001, 10) that has different result from Math.pow(0.0000000001,10), like last decimal place. What do you suggest for dealing that ? is it best accuracy that we can get in ?

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to improve on that without spending a month studying the guts of the floating-point representation.  (`Math.pow` is going to be the more accurate implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

On my system I have

```
-2147483648
2147483647
```

For `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` respectively.  So you should see the problem in the line

```
exp *= -1;
```

Comment: Every system will have those values. It's platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the real issue is that, since the sign doesn't flip on the MIN_VALUE, the sign cascades to the exp/2. and the 'negative power' case applies. If we split it, it's easier:

```
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
    double result = 1.00000;
    boolean negative = false;
    
    if(n <0) {
        negative = true;
        n= -n;
    }
    
    result=power(x,n);
    if(negative) {
        result = 1/result;
    }
    return result;
}

private double power(double a, int n) {
    if(n ==0 || a==1) return 1;// a^0 = 1, 1^n = 1
    double x=power(a,n/2);
    
    if(n%2 == 0) return x*x;
    else return a*x*x;
}
```